# ¿Como cambio las restricciones de intregridad referencial una vez creadas las tablas?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Tengo una tabla llamada `usuario`. El código que use para crearla es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cumplimiento`.`usuario` (
  `idusuario` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `pass` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `rol` INT NOT NULL,
  `activo` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `pregunta` VARCHAR(55) NULL,
  `respuesta` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idusuario`),
  INDEX `fk_usuario_rol1_idx` (`rol` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_usuario_rol1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`rol`)
    REFERENCES `cumplimiento`.`rol` (`rol`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

La tabla se crea correctamente y todo esta bien. La situación es la siguiente. Yo necesito hacer un `UPDATE` a `idusuario` y que ese cambio se refleje en las tablas en donde este campo es una llave foránea.

Encontre que la forma de hacer eso es utilizar la instrucción:

```
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Por ejemplo, tengo esta otra tabla persona, cuyo código es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cumplimiento`.`persona` (
  `cif` INT NOT NULL,
  `idusuario` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `numero_impresiones` INT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_persona_usuario1_idx` (`idusuario` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`cif`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_persona_usuario1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idusuario`)
    REFERENCES `cumplimiento`.`usuario` (`idusuario`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Y entiendo que bajo las `REFERENCES` esta mi campo `idusuario`. Tambien entiendo que es en esta tabla que tengo que cambiar el `ON UPDATE NO ACTION` a `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, y asi sucesivamente en otras tablas donde tenga este campo como llave foránea.

Ahora bien, básicamente no lo he hecho porque tengo un poco de temor de que algo pueda pasar a  mis tablas e intuyo que hay una forma facil de hacerlo. ¿Como hago para cambiar eso? ¿Tengo que usar el mismo script y solo cambiar esa parte de cada tabla? o quizas, ¿se puede hacer de alguna forma en Workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que no hay forma de actualizar un constraint, lo que tienes que hacer son dos cosas:

1. Eliminar el constraint actual
2. Agregar un nuevo constraint

Por lo tanto, tendrías que hacer:

```
-- Eliminar el constraint
ALTER TABLE `cumplimiento`.`usuario`
DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_usuario_rol1`;

-- Crearlo nuevamente
ALTER TABLE `cumplimiento`.`usuario`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_usuario_rol1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`rol`)
    REFERENCES `cumplimiento`.`rol` (`rol`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Puedes consultar la documentación con respecto al uso de [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: Gracias Cesar, en efecto esto es lo que se debe hacer. Trasteando el Workbench, encontre que hay un forma en la interfaz gráfica para hacerlo y que al final ejecuta estas mismas instrucciones y lo pondre como una respuesta complementaria. +1

Answer (score 1):

En efecto, la respuesta de César es la correcta. Gracias a la respuesta de César, pude encontrar una forma de hacerlo en Workbench, de una forma gráfica.

---

1. Click derecho en la tabla, se selecciona `Alter Table` y en la parte de abajo se seleccion `Foreign Keys`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

2. Se selecciona la llave foránea a la cual se tiene que cambiar la acción.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

3. En la parte de la derecha, en la parte que dice Foreign Key Options se puede cambiar la opción.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

4. Y al final, Workbench se encargará de generar el mismo script que Cesar ha sugerido para obtener los cambios deseados.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]